# How do I pass parameters to a factory service at runtime?

Tags: symfony

At the moment I'm instantiating a 3rd party class inside one of my services:

```
$message = new ChatMessage($apiKey);
$message->setFrom($fromUser);
$message->setBody($messageText);
$message->etc ...
```

Which I want to turn into a service. The apiKey is determined at runtime depending on where the message is being sent, so I need to be able to set it at runtime. I've got as far as creating this config for the service:

```
class ChatMessageFactory
{
    function createChatMessage($apiKey) {
        return new ChatMessage($apiKey);
    }
}

services.yml:-
services:
    chatmessage_manager:
        class: ChatMessage
        factory: [ChatMessageFactory, createChatMessage]
        arguments: ["%flow.apiKey%"]
```

but how do I pass my parameter to createChatMessage? It's not known when the container is created?

Comment: Does your code work? have you seen http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html#passing-arguments-to-the-factory-method

Comment: Into createChatMessage the argument you're passing so far is an array

Comment: @smarber I have seen that example, but the key I'm passing in isn't defined until just before where I instantiate the class now, ie without the service.

I don't want to pass the whole container in, so the factory is passed as a parameter to this servcie ...

We have a solution that seems to work at the moment, but doesn't feel right, so I'll update question with that when I know it works properly.

Comment: IMHO it doesn't seem to be possible do set configuration for service at runtime (as the whole idea is that container is already initialized and conifugured by the time you're running your domain code). So I expose factory as a service and simply create chat message using `$factory->createChat($api)` . The chat instance will not be available in the container, but I don't care. If I really need all instantiated chats, I would have created service `ChatRegistry` which would enumerate all created chats. (or simply method on factory  `$factory->getChats()` returning array or map of charts.

Answer (score -3):

it's all there in the docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html#passing-arguments-to-the-factory-method

and regarding parameters at all:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html

so your approach seems correct, you might want to check you parameter name.

Comment: The example shows passing another service as a param, or a param that's defined in config, the param I need to pass isn't defined until the last minute so I can't pass it in config.

Comment: Again, it's all in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files
whatever you can se in paameters.yml  as parameter:  value, you can also set as $container->setParameter('parameter','value');

Comment: No.  It's not in the documentation.  Stop and read his question.

Comment: Well it is, he can set the parameter inside the container and fetch it in the factory service or set it as a field in the factory service itself at any time

Comment: Well.  Not to drag this out too far but he wants to do is something like $service = $container->get('factory',$apiKey).  He wants to pass a request driven parameter which is not available when the container is built.  Won't work of course.  He needs to do:  $service = $container->get('factory')->create($apiKey); and adjust his factory code accordingly.

Comment: Cerad  is right. the container configuration is compiled at bootstrap time, you can't set parameters at runtime. The only way to achieve this, as far as I know, is cerad's solution: you need to create a factory (which can be defined as a service) and the pass the $key parameter at runtime to the factory method.